# Selecting maximum value for a column with contraint

Tags: sql

Table is as follows

```
Company, Vertical, Counts
```

For each company I want to get the SUM of counts based on a specific Vertical having the highest count

```
Company       Vertical             Counts 
IBM           Finance              10
IBM           R&D                   5
IBM           PR                    2
```

I would like to get the following output

```
IBM       Finance   17
```

Comment: Your question is inconsistent. "I want to get the SUM of counts based on a specific Vertical having the highest count" seems you want finance = 10, but you then say you want finance = 17. Do you want the vertical or the company?

Answer (score 1):

A self-join should do it.

```
select company, vertical, total_count
from(
    select sum(counts) as total_count
    from table
    )a
cross join table
where counts=(select max(counts) from table);
```

Depending on your RDBMS, you can also use a window function (eg sum(count) over () as total_count) and not have to worry about the cross join.

Comment: Won't give correct output: how does this extract the finance row?

Comment: Well, counts=(select max(counts) from table) precisely when vertical='Finance', therefore the row produced by my query above will be 'IBM','Finance',17.

Comment: ah, I thought I'd mentioned "if there was more than one company"

Answer (score 1):

It's a twist on the problem of ["How to get the MAX row"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/how-to-get-the-max-row/1004#1004) (DBA.SE link)

1. get total and highest vertical per Company in a simple aggregate
2. use these to identify the row in the source table

Something like this, untested

```
SELECT
    t.Company, t.Vertical, m.CompanyCount
FROM
    ( --get total and highest vertical  per Company
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS CompanyCount,
        MAX(Vertical) AS CompanyMaxVertical,
        Company
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY Company
    ) m
    JOIN --back to get the row for that company with  highest vertical
    MyTable t ON m.Company = t.Company AND m.CompanyMaxVertical = t.Vertical
```

Edit: this is closer to standard SQL than a ROW_NUMBER because we don't know the platform

Answer (score 0):

```
select Company,
       Vertical,
       SumCounts
from (       
        select Company,
               Vertical,
               row_number() over(partition by Company order by Counts desc) as rn,
               sum(Counts) over(partition by Company) as SumCounts
        from YourTable
     ) as T
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT company,
       vertical,
       total_sum
FROM (
    SELECT Company, 
           Vertical, 
           sum(counts) over (partition by null) as total_sum,
           rank() over (order by counts desc) as count_rank
    FROM the_table
) t
WHERE count_rank = 1
```